# handle shared text file and text in android app with SEND intent

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I have an activity which handles "SEND" intent whenever you share something.
Below is my code for that activity.

**ShareSendMessageActivity.java**

```
public class ShareSendMessageActivity {

    boolean isDualPane;
    Bundle bundle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {

                // Get intent, action and MIME type
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String action = intent.getAction();
                String type = intent.getType();

                if ((Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) || (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action)) && type != null)) {
                    bundle = new Bundle();
                    handleSharedFile(intent);
                }


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void handleSharedFile(Intent intent) {
        ArrayList<Uri> listImageUri = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> listPath = new ArrayList<>();
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_SEND)) {
            Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            listImageUri.add(imageUri);
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE)) {
            listImageUri = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        }

        for (Uri u : listImageUri) {
            String path = FileUtils.getPath(this, u);
            listPath.add(path);
        }

        bundle.putBoolean(IConstants.KEY_IS_FROM_SHARE, true);
        bundle.putStringArrayList(IConstants.KEY_SHARED_FILE_PATH, listPath);

        Intent callingIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        callingIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        callingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        callingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(callingIntent);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }


}
```

Now when I share *.txt file this code works fine. But when I share any text or URL from chrome in the app like below screenshot.

**1. Share URL**
[image]

**2. Share Text**
[image]

So in both case it throws a null pointer exception because for this code

```
Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

I get **imageuri = null.**

So how can I handle this in the same activity. Because when I share .txt file , share URL or share text, i get same mime type that is "text/plain". 
As per my requirement in chat application, if I share .txt file it should 
 get attached to recipient and if i share text or URL it should send message to recipient. But how can I differentiate that whether this intent action came from .txt file or (text,URL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no `EXTRA_STREAM` extra, look in `EXTRA_TEXT` for the text.

Comment: Currently handled scenario as per your condition and it is working fine.